# Dojo: Copying a node tree

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using Dojo as JavaScript framework. What I would like to do is copy a tree of nodes and put it under the copied tree. Specifically, I have a table row with plenty of code within it. I would like to add a new table row that is the exact copy of the above row, with some ids changed here and there.

What would be the best way to do this?

I was thinking of making a deep copy of the original row and provide it to document.createElement().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM method `cloneNode` will do what you want; pass `true` to it to make a deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simpliest and fastest way to do this is to copy innerHTML in new tr node. You can change ids with regexp.